# How can I have 5 visits with with zero unique visitors?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

According to Google Analytics, I had **5 visits from zero unique visitors**. Is that a bug or did I perhaps implement something wrongly? Or hasn't the data processing finished yet (I created this view 2 days ago)?

The view is based on an `include custom filter` that's supposed to include only traffic from any of three ip addresses. The regex I used for this is

```
62\.58\.32\.193|77\.172\.143\.12$|213\.125\.166\.98
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be the way Google defines unique Visitors. Sometimes I have been visiting my own website periodically and I ended up showing up as a unique visitor (My site isn't so popular so it's easy for me to track that). I would either have to say that it has to do with the nature of visits or the actual way of unique visitors. According to google this is how the find unique visitors

> The other Unique Visitors metric calculation (Calculation #2) is based
>   on the __utma cookie. Calculation #2 is used when segmenting the
>   Audience Overview report or when viewing Unique Visitors over any
>   dimension other than date. As such, Calculation #2 is used in custom
>   reports to allow for the calculation of Unique Visitors over any
>   dimension, such as browser, city, or traffic source.

source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, there are problems with Google Analytics reporting.  Check the [product forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/analytics).  For example, here is an issue that happened on Nov 11, 2013:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/fsurDK8AOcY

This issue can also crop up when you are [using the page dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en).  Unique visitors are only assigned to the first page in a visit as described [here](http://www.michaelwhitaker.com/blog/2010/04/23/unique-visitors-0-visits-and-pages-in-web-analytics/).  But, it doesn't seem like that is the case for you.

Finally, its possible, analogous to the page dimension situation, that unique visitors are only assigned to the first IP address that a visitor came from.  If that is true, then if the people who came to your site had previously come from a different IP address, then they wouldn't show up as unique visitors in your filter.